# QString arg ambuguity - format %1000%2 with arg

Tags: c++, qt

I want to format a QString with the following:

`QString("%1000%2").arg("ABC", "DEF");`

I expected the output to be `"ABC000DEF"` but actually it is `"%1000ABC"`.

How can I get over the ambuguity ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not seeing "%1" "000" "%2", it's seeing "%10" "00" "%2"(placemarkers range from 1 to 99)

A work-around could be

```
QString("%1%2%3").arg("ABC", "000", "DEF");
```

Comment: Not quite, placemarkers are in the range of 1 to 99, so it's actually seeing "%10" "00" "%2".

Comment: The principle remains the same

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround would be using `replace` instead of `arg`, which doesn't change the original format string but takes more typing:

`QString("%1000%2").replace("%1", "ABC").replace("%2", "DEF");`